# what are all the disadvantages and benefits accessing a static html page from DAM.?

Tags: aem

What are the advantages and disadvantages, If we create a static page, place it in cq DAM and access it through url redirections from server end?

Answer (score 0):

The DAM is principally for assets - and implies binary assets (images, PDFs, etc) and really wants to create "renditions" for multiple uses, like thumbnails.

HTML/markup makes more sense as content - and you can create a component to provide an authoring interface to change it.  Then you can point to it via XREF components.

Further, a full page's worth of markup isn't likely to be reusable.  It would make sense to break it down to more re-usable components (header, footer, left/right rail, main content).